# Accessing Website On Offline Network With Android 11+

Tags: android, networking, iot, offline

I have a webserver that is running on a network that is not connected to the internet.

The webserver serves up a website.

When I connect an android phone to it, I am able to run the website that is on the webserver

But with certain phones that are running Android 11 I need to disable the mobile data on the phone before it will try to access the website over wifi. It seems the phone will not try to request the url on the wifi network because it doesn't have internet, so it defaults to using the 4G/5G Cellular internet connection. This is too bad, because I would like the phone to use the wifi connection.

I would think that perhaops I could "force" the phone to use the wifi connection by typing the IP address in the browser's URL bar (eg. http://192.168.211.1/index.php), however it seems that even with the "local ip" it will still try to use the 4G/5G network instead of the "offline wifi" network.

The only workaround I have found is to disable moblie data on the phone, but this is not ideal.

I would think that some IoT devices would have an offline webserver used for configuation/control.

Is there a certain port or settings I should be using?
Is there a designated port that the browser/OS would expect to be on an offline network?

Basically, how can I make the phone use the wifi, even though the wifi is not connected to the internet?

Thanks so much for any pointers!

Comment: Definitely interested in seeing the answer to this as well. I've seen this issue happen on Android 11, as well as Samsung S-series devices all the way back to the S8.

Comment: Would these provide any clues on how to make this work?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special-use_domain_name

Comment: Is this a programming problem? If so, where is your code that makes the request to `ConnectivityManager`?

Comment: This is not a programming problem from the android side. I am wondering from the standpoint of an offline webserver/website how can we can make android phones access the webserver via the “offline” WiFi and not via their cellular data.